# transliterating cyrillic to latin with javascript function

Tags: javascript, transliteration

I made this function:

```
function transliterate(word){

    var answer = "";

    A = new Array();
    A["Ё"]="YO";A["Й"]="I";A["Ц"]="TS";A["У"]="U";A["К"]="K";A["Е"]="E";A["Н"]="N";A["Г"]="G";A["Ш"]="SH";A["Щ"]="SCH";A["З"]="Z";A["Х"]="H";A["Ъ"]="'";
    A["ё"]="yo";A["й"]="i";A["ц"]="ts";A["у"]="u";A["к"]="k";A["е"]="e";A["н"]="n";A["г"]="g";A["ш"]="sh";A["щ"]="sch";A["з"]="z";A["х"]="h";A["ъ"]="'";
    A["Ф"]="F";A["Ы"]="I";A["В"]="V";A["А"]="A";A["П"]="P";A["Р"]="R";A["О"]="O";A["Л"]="L";A["Д"]="D";A["Ж"]="ZH";A["Э"]="E";
    A["ф"]="f";A["ы"]="i";A["в"]="v";A["а"]="a";A["п"]="p";A["р"]="r";A["о"]="o";A["л"]="l";A["д"]="d";A["ж"]="zh";A["э"]="e";
    A["Я"]="YA";A["Ч"]="CH";A["С"]="S";A["М"]="M";A["И"]="I";A["Т"]="T";A["Ь"]="'";A["Б"]="B";A["Ю"]="YU";
    A["я"]="ya";A["ч"]="ch";A["с"]="s";A["м"]="m";A["и"]="i";A["т"]="t";A["ь"]="'";A["б"]="b";A["ю"]="yu";

for (i in word){

    if (A[word[i]] === 'undefined'){
        answer += word[i];
        }
    else {
        answer += A[word[i]];
        }

return answer;
}
}
```

Now it should transliterate cyrillic text to latin and let latin simply pass. But it only manages to transliterate the first later and in case of latin it gives undefined as an answer. Could anyone give me an idea, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: An ide?  As in an _integrated development environment_, or an _idea_?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Couple of things...

1. Use `undefined` instead of 'undefined'
2. Don't put the return in the loop
3. Use hasOwnProperty to filter out functions and properties on the prototype
4. Use `[]` instead of `new Array()`
5. Use an `{}` instead of an `[]`
6. Use lower case variables instead of upper case. Uppercase is reserved for constructors

Here is the code

```
function transliterate(word){
    var answer = ""
      , a = {};

   a["Ё"]="YO";a["Й"]="I";a["Ц"]="TS";a["У"]="U";a["К"]="K";a["Е"]="E";a["Н"]="N";a["Г"]="G";a["Ш"]="SH";a["Щ"]="SCH";a["З"]="Z";a["Х"]="H";a["Ъ"]="'";
   a["ё"]="yo";a["й"]="i";a["ц"]="ts";a["у"]="u";a["к"]="k";a["е"]="e";a["н"]="n";a["г"]="g";a["ш"]="sh";a["щ"]="sch";a["з"]="z";a["х"]="h";a["ъ"]="'";
   a["Ф"]="F";a["Ы"]="I";a["В"]="V";a["А"]="A";a["П"]="P";a["Р"]="R";a["О"]="O";a["Л"]="L";a["Д"]="D";a["Ж"]="ZH";a["Э"]="E";
   a["ф"]="f";a["ы"]="i";a["в"]="v";a["а"]="a";a["п"]="p";a["р"]="r";a["о"]="o";a["л"]="l";a["д"]="d";a["ж"]="zh";a["э"]="e";
   a["Я"]="Ya";a["Ч"]="CH";a["С"]="S";a["М"]="M";a["И"]="I";a["Т"]="T";a["Ь"]="'";a["Б"]="B";a["Ю"]="YU";
   a["я"]="ya";a["ч"]="ch";a["с"]="s";a["м"]="m";a["и"]="i";a["т"]="t";a["ь"]="'";a["б"]="b";a["ю"]="yu";

   for (i in word){
     if (word.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       if (a[word[i]] === undefined){
         answer += word[i];
       } else {
         answer += a[word[i]];
       }
     }
   }
   return answer;
}
```

More functional one is like this...

```
var a = {"Ё":"YO","Й":"I","Ц":"TS","У":"U","К":"K","Е":"E","Н":"N","Г":"G","Ш":"SH","Щ":"SCH","З":"Z","Х":"H","Ъ":"'","ё":"yo","й":"i","ц":"ts","у":"u","к":"k","е":"e","н":"n","г":"g","ш":"sh","щ":"sch","з":"z","х":"h","ъ":"'","Ф":"F","Ы":"I","В":"V","А":"A","П":"P","Р":"R","О":"O","Л":"L","Д":"D","Ж":"ZH","Э":"E","ф":"f","ы":"i","в":"v","а":"a","п":"p","р":"r","о":"o","л":"l","д":"d","ж":"zh","э":"e","Я":"Ya","Ч":"CH","С":"S","М":"M","И":"I","Т":"T","Ь":"'","Б":"B","Ю":"YU","я":"ya","ч":"ch","с":"s","м":"m","и":"i","т":"t","ь":"'","б":"b","ю":"yu"};

function transliterate(word){
  return word.split('').map(function (char) { 
    return a[char] || char; 
  }).join("");
}
```

Comment: I find myself revisiting this question every now and then and I'm pretty sure this is the most compact and usable code addressing this issue one will find out there. Thanks!

Comment: Liked the functional one. Compact and concise!

Comment: Hi, do you know if there is a library that does that ? (would need it for other alphabet too)

Comment: There are errors here: for example  a["А"]="a" ??

Answer (score 27):

In my projects I am using this method of transliterating:

```
var transliterate = function(text) {

    text = text
        .replace(/\u0401/g, 'YO')
        .replace(/\u0419/g, 'I')
        .replace(/\u0426/g, 'TS')
        .replace(/\u0423/g, 'U')
        .replace(/\u041A/g, 'K')
        .replace(/\u0415/g, 'E')
        .replace(/\u041D/g, 'N')
        .replace(/\u0413/g, 'G')
        .replace(/\u0428/g, 'SH')
        .replace(/\u0429/g, 'SCH')
        .replace(/\u0417/g, 'Z')
        .replace(/\u0425/g, 'H')
        .replace(/\u042A/g, '')
        .replace(/\u0451/g, 'yo')
        .replace(/\u0439/g, 'i')
        .replace(/\u0446/g, 'ts')
        .replace(/\u0443/g, 'u')
        .replace(/\u043A/g, 'k')
        .replace(/\u0435/g, 'e')
        .replace(/\u043D/g, 'n')
        .replace(/\u0433/g, 'g')
        .replace(/\u0448/g, 'sh')
        .replace(/\u0449/g, 'sch')
        .replace(/\u0437/g, 'z')
        .replace(/\u0445/g, 'h')
        .replace(/\u044A/g, "'")
        .replace(/\u0424/g, 'F')
        .replace(/\u042B/g, 'I')
        .replace(/\u0412/g, 'V')
        .replace(/\u0410/g, 'a')
        .replace(/\u041F/g, 'P')
        .replace(/\u0420/g, 'R')
        .replace(/\u041E/g, 'O')
        .replace(/\u041B/g, 'L')
        .replace(/\u0414/g, 'D')
        .replace(/\u0416/g, 'ZH')
        .replace(/\u042D/g, 'E')
        .replace(/\u0444/g, 'f')
        .replace(/\u044B/g, 'i')
        .replace(/\u0432/g, 'v')
        .replace(/\u0430/g, 'a')
        .replace(/\u043F/g, 'p')
        .replace(/\u0440/g, 'r')
        .replace(/\u043E/g, 'o')
        .replace(/\u043B/g, 'l')
        .replace(/\u0434/g, 'd')
        .replace(/\u0436/g, 'zh')
        .replace(/\u044D/g, 'e')
        .replace(/\u042F/g, 'Ya')
        .replace(/\u0427/g, 'CH')
        .replace(/\u0421/g, 'S')
        .replace(/\u041C/g, 'M')
        .replace(/\u0418/g, 'I')
        .replace(/\u0422/g, 'T')
        .replace(/\u042C/g, "'")
        .replace(/\u0411/g, 'B')
        .replace(/\u042E/g, 'YU')
        .replace(/\u044F/g, 'ya')
        .replace(/\u0447/g, 'ch')
        .replace(/\u0441/g, 's')
        .replace(/\u043C/g, 'm')
        .replace(/\u0438/g, 'i')
        .replace(/\u0442/g, 't')
        .replace(/\u044C/g, "'")
        .replace(/\u0431/g, 'b')
        .replace(/\u044E/g, 'yu');

    return text;
};
```

Run this sample to transliterate:

```
transliterate('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ');
```

I have replaced all russian letters with their unicode analogs (each letter begins with \u) to solve problems with encoding in Javascript file.

To check the execution  speed, i took the best answer to this question, and compared it with my example. My method appeared to be faster in several times (0.16 ms in Firebug :-).

[image: speed comparison in firebug]

Comment: ... are you developing in IE?

Answer (score 7):

Do not use an array for this task. Do not use `for in` to iterate a string. Do not check against the string `"undefined"`. Do not `return` within the `for` loop.

```
function transliterate(word) {
    var A = {};
    var result = '';

    A["Ё"]="YO";A["Й"]="I";A["Ц"]="TS";A["У"]="U";A["К"]="K";A["Е"]="E";A["Н"]="N";A["Г"]="G";A["Ш"]="SH";A["Щ"]="SCH";A["З"]="Z";A["Х"]="H";A["Ъ"]="'";
    A["ё"]="yo";A["й"]="i";A["ц"]="ts";A["у"]="u";A["к"]="k";A["е"]="e";A["н"]="n";A["г"]="g";A["ш"]="sh";A["щ"]="sch";A["з"]="z";A["х"]="h";A["ъ"]="'";
    A["Ф"]="F";A["Ы"]="I";A["В"]="V";A["А"]="A";A["П"]="P";A["Р"]="R";A["О"]="O";A["Л"]="L";A["Д"]="D";A["Ж"]="ZH";A["Э"]="E";
    A["ф"]="f";A["ы"]="i";A["в"]="v";A["а"]="a";A["п"]="p";A["р"]="r";A["о"]="o";A["л"]="l";A["д"]="d";A["ж"]="zh";A["э"]="e";
    A["Я"]="YA";A["Ч"]="CH";A["С"]="S";A["М"]="M";A["И"]="I";A["Т"]="T";A["Ь"]="'";A["Б"]="B";A["Ю"]="YU";
    A["я"]="ya";A["ч"]="ch";A["с"]="s";A["м"]="m";A["и"]="i";A["т"]="t";A["ь"]="'";A["б"]="b";A["ю"]="yu";

    for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        var c = word.charAt(i);

        result += A[c] || c;
    }

    return result;
}
```

[Here is a jsFiddle demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/JVJ8a/)

Comment: Do not put `var i` in the loop construct. Do not put `var c` in the loop body. Why: [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html) +1 otherwise

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I know that it defines them as a function scope, and I'm perfectly happy with the fact. It is simply a coding convention. Thank you, though.

Comment: @ Charmander: A bad one. If you want to actively mislead the people maintaining your code, though, by all means carry on. ;-) (Note that `let` is coming to JavaScript, which just makes this use of `var` more precarious.)

Answer (score 4):

Your primary problem is that the `return` is in the wrong place. It's *inside* your loop, so it returns on the first iteration. Change it to:

```
function transliterate(word){

    var answer = "";

    A = new Array();
    A["Ё"]="YO";A["Й"]="I";A["Ц"]="TS";A["У"]="U";A["К"]="K";A["Е"]="E";A["Н"]="N";A["Г"]="G";A["Ш"]="SH";A["Щ"]="SCH";A["З"]="Z";A["Х"]="H";A["Ъ"]="'";
    A["ё"]="yo";A["й"]="i";A["ц"]="ts";A["у"]="u";A["к"]="k";A["е"]="e";A["н"]="n";A["г"]="g";A["ш"]="sh";A["щ"]="sch";A["з"]="z";A["х"]="h";A["ъ"]="'";
    A["Ф"]="F";A["Ы"]="I";A["В"]="V";A["А"]="A";A["П"]="P";A["Р"]="R";A["О"]="O";A["Л"]="L";A["Д"]="D";A["Ж"]="ZH";A["Э"]="E";
    A["ф"]="f";A["ы"]="i";A["в"]="v";A["а"]="a";A["п"]="p";A["р"]="r";A["о"]="o";A["л"]="l";A["д"]="d";A["ж"]="zh";A["э"]="e";
    A["Я"]="YA";A["Ч"]="CH";A["С"]="S";A["М"]="M";A["И"]="I";A["Т"]="T";A["Ь"]="'";A["Б"]="B";A["Ю"]="YU";
    A["я"]="ya";A["ч"]="ch";A["с"]="s";A["м"]="m";A["и"]="i";A["т"]="t";A["ь"]="'";A["б"]="b";A["ю"]="yu";

    for (i in word){

        if (A[word[i]] === 'undefined'){
            answer += word[i];
            }
        else {
            answer += A[word[i]];
            }

    }
    return answer; // <=== Was *above* the } on the previous line
}
```

Note that I've fixed the indentation. Consistent indentation helps you avoid these sorts of bugs.

---

Note 1: There's ***nothing*** about your `A` object that uses the fact it's an `Array`. You're just using it as a map. In JavaScript, all objects are maps, so rather than `A = new Array();` just use `A = {};`.

Note 2: `A` and `i` are never declared in your function, so you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). To fix it, declare them with `var`.

Note 3: Neither using `for..in` to loop through the characters of a string, nor using `[]` to index into the string, is reliable across JavaScript engines. Instead, use `for (i = 0; i < word.length; ++i)` and then `ch = word.charAt(i);` to get the character at that position, then use `ch` in your code within the loop.

Note 4: You can use the [*Curiously powerful `||` operator*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to shorten your code, e.g.:

```
answer += A[ch] || ch;
```

Answer (score 2):

Russian symbols in js don't work at all at my system. I don't know why. So I use the next code for this:

It will not only transliterate but replace all punctuation with '_' and lowercase everything.

```js
function translit(str){
 var sp = '_'; 
 var text = str.toLowerCase();
 var transl = { 
  '\u0430': 'a', '\u0431': 'b', '\u0432': 'v', '\u0433': 'g', '\u0434': 'd', '\u0435': 'e', '\u0451': 'e', '\u0436': 'zh',
  '\u0437': 'z', '\u0438': 'i', '\u0439': 'j', '\u043a': 'k', '\u043b': 'l', '\u043c': 'm', '\u043d': 'n', '\u043e': 'o',
  '\u043f': 'p', '\u0440': 'r', '\u0441': 's', '\u0442': 't', '\u0443': 'u', '\u0444': 'f', '\u0445': 'h', '\u0446': 'c', 
  '\u0447': 'ch', '\u0448': 'sh', '\u0449': 'shch', '\u044a': '\'', '\u044b': 'y', '\u044c': '', '\u044d': 'e', '\u044e': 'yu',
  '\u044f': 'ya',  
  '\u00AB':'_', '\u00BB':'_', // «»
  ' ': sp, '_': sp, '`': sp, '~': sp, 
  '!': sp, '@': sp, '#': sp, '$': sp,
  '%': sp, '^': sp, '&': sp, '*': sp, '(': sp, ')': sp, '-': sp, '\=': sp,
  '+': sp, '[': sp, ']': sp, '\\': sp, '|': sp, '/': sp, '.': sp, ',': sp,
  '{': sp, '}': sp, '\'': sp, '"': sp, ';': sp, ':': sp, '?': sp, '<': sp,
  '>': sp, '№': sp     
 }
    var result = '';
 var curent_sim = '';
    for(i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if(transl[text[i]] != undefined) {   
   if(curent_sim != transl[text[i]] || curent_sim != sp){
    result += transl[text[i]];
    curent_sim = transl[text[i]];    
   }     
  } else {
   result += text[i];
   curent_sim = text[i];
  }  
    }
 result = result.replace(/^_/, '').replace(/_$/, ''); // trim
 return result
}

var result = translit('Привет Мир!');
document.getElementById('alias').value = result;
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="alias" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The code was originally taken here: http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/js/137-transliteracija_stroki_na_javascript.html and then refactored.

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest, most readable, and extensible way that I have found to do it in TypeScript:

```
const cyrToLat = (str: string): string => {
  const a: Record<string, string> = {};
  a["а"] = "a";
  a["А"] = "А";
  a["Б"] = "B";
  a["б"] = "b";
  a["В"] = "V";
  a["в"] = "v";
  a["Г"] = "G";
  a["г"] = "g";
  a["Ґ"] = "G";
  a["ґ"] = "g";
  a["Д"] = "D";
  a["д"] = "d";
  a["Е"] = "E";
  a["е"] = "e";
  a["Ё"] = "YO";
  a["ё"] = "yo";
  a["є"] = "ie";
  a["Є"] = "Ye";
  a["Ж"] = "ZH";
  a["ж"] = "zh";
  a["З"] = "Z";
  a["з"] = "z";
  a["И"] = "I";
  a["и"] = "i";
  a["І"] = "I";
  a["і"] = "i";
  a["ї"] = "i";
  a["Ї"] = "Yi";
  a["Й"] = "I";
  a["й"] = "i";
  a["К"] = "K";
  a["к"] = "k";
  a["Л"] = "L";
  a["л"] = "l";
  a["М"] = "M";
  a["м"] = "m";
  a["Н"] = "N";
  a["н"] = "n";
  a["О"] = "O";
  a["о"] = "o";
  a["П"] = "P";
  a["п"] = "p";
  a["Р"] = "R";
  a["р"] = "r";
  a["С"] = "S";
  a["с"] = "s";
  a["Т"] = "T";
  a["т"] = "t";
  a["У"] = "U";
  a["у"] = "u";
  a["Ф"] = "F";
  a["ф"] = "f";
  a["Х"] = "H";
  a["х"] = "h";
  a["Ц"] = "TS";
  a["ц"] = "ts";
  a["Ч"] = "CH";
  a["ч"] = "ch";
  a["Ш"] = "SH";
  a["ш"] = "sh";
  a["Щ"] = "SCH";
  a["щ"] = "sch";
  a["Ъ"] = "'";
  a["ъ"] = "'";
  a["Ы"] = "I";
  a["ы"] = "i";
  a["Ь"] = "'";
  a["ь"] = "'";
  a["Э"] = "E";
  a["э"] = "e";
  a["Ю"] = "YU";
  a["ю"] = "yu";
  a["Я"] = "Ya";
  a["я"] = "ya";
  return str
    .split("")
    .map((char) => a[char] || char)
    .join("");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace 'ъ' and 'ь' with empty strings, you should modify
@split-your-infinity solution in this way:

```
var a = {"Ё":"YO","Й":"I","Ц":"TS","У":"U","К":"K","Е":"E","Н":"N","Г":"G","Ш":"SH","Щ":"SCH","З":"Z","Х":"H","Ъ":"","ё":"yo","й":"i","ц":"ts","у":"u","к":"k","е":"e","н":"n","г":"g","ш":"sh","щ":"sch","з":"z","х":"h","ъ":"","Ф":"F","Ы":"I","В":"V","А":"a","П":"P","Р":"R","О":"O","Л":"L","Д":"D","Ж":"ZH","Э":"E","ф":"f","ы":"i","в":"v","а":"a","п":"p","р":"r","о":"o","л":"l","д":"d","ж":"zh","э":"e","Я":"Ya","Ч":"CH","С":"S","М":"M","И":"I","Т":"T","Ь":"","Б":"B","Ю":"YU","я":"ya","ч":"ch","с":"s","м":"m","и":"i","т":"t","ь":"","б":"b","ю":"yu"};

function transliterate(word){
  return word.split('').map(function (char) { 
    return a.hasOwnProperty(char) ? a[char] : char; 
  }).join("");
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to get 'Uncaught TypeError: word.split is not a function', you have to cast the 'word' parameter to the sting. E.g.: transiterate(""+someTexOrNumberVar). Otherwise you have to do it inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

By combining recommendations of Bart Riemens and T.J. Crowder I came up with this code, that seams to do the trick nicely:

```
 function transliterate(word){

    var answer = "";
    var a = {}

    a["Ё"]="YO";a["Й"]="I";a["Ц"]="TS";a["У"]="U";a["К"]="K";a["Е"]="E";a["Н"]="N";a["Г"]="G";a["Ш"]="SH";a["Щ"]="SCH";a["З"]="Z";a["Х"]="H";a["Ъ"]="'";
    a["ё"]="yo";a["й"]="i";a["ц"]="ts";a["у"]="u";a["к"]="k";a["е"]="e";a["н"]="n";a["г"]="g";a["ш"]="sh";a["щ"]="sch";a["з"]="z";a["х"]="h";a["ъ"]="'";
    a["Ф"]="F";a["Ы"]="I";a["В"]="V";a["А"]="a";a["П"]="P";a["Р"]="R";a["О"]="O";a["Л"]="L";a["Д"]="D";a["Ж"]="ZH";a["Э"]="E";
    a["ф"]="f";a["ы"]="i";a["в"]="v";a["а"]="a";a["п"]="p";a["р"]="r";a["о"]="o";a["л"]="l";a["д"]="d";a["ж"]="zh";a["э"]="e";
    a["Я"]="Ya";a["Ч"]="CH";a["С"]="S";a["М"]="M";a["И"]="I";a["Т"]="T";a["Ь"]="'";a["Б"]="B";a["Ю"]="YU";
    a["я"]="ya";a["ч"]="ch";a["с"]="s";a["м"]="m";a["и"]="i";a["т"]="t";a["ь"]="'";a["б"]="b";a["ю"]="yu";

    for (i = 0; i < word.length; ++i){

        answer += a[word[i]] === undefined ? word[i] : a[word[i]];
    }   
    return answer;
}
```

Than you!

Comment: Cool! Did you see my latest functional version! :-)

Comment: @Bart Riemens Didn't notice it at first, but it seams shorter and more universal.