# Transliteration letter on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, transliteration

is there a way to transliterate letter from latin to cirilic when user make input, etc.

When user type letter 'F' to trasliterate to 'Ф' in real time.

This google solutions is deprecated [link](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started)

Thanks,
P

Comment: Do you think the opposite way of this can help you? : https://stackoverflow.com/q/11404047/4636715