# Convert Cyrillic character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I got a new requirement that whenever Cyrillic character involved in a string i need to convert it to ENGLISH, using javascript.

Could anyone please help me here with the code?

Comment: Do you mean translate to english or transliterate to latin characters?

Comment: Also: maybe its a douplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404047/transliterating-cyrillic-to-latin-with-javascript-function